# Emplacing an instance with constant fields fails to compile (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constants, emplace

I have an example_class with two constant fields. When I try to emplace an object of that class into a std::vector, I get various errors such as "error: object of type 'example_class' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted". Does anyone know what is going on here? If I remove the const in example class, the code compiles without problems.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class example_class {
    public:
    example_class(int v1, int v2) : val1(v1), val2(v2) {}

    private:
    const int val1, val2;
};

int main() {

    vector<example_class> *vec = new vector<example_class>();
    vec->emplace(vec->begin() + 1, 13131, 12313);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When `std::vector` needs additional space it needs to be able to move (or copy) the existing elements into the new space.  It can't in this case because the class contains `const` values. See [Type requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)

Comment: Unrelated, but `new` is totally useless here, `vector<example_class> vec;` does the same.

Comment: I *think* the `emplace` call uses the copy **assignment** operator, which can't really be implemented when there are `const` data members.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Does anyone know why it compiles successfully if I use ```emplace_back``` rather than ```emplace```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trying to use the `std::vector<T>::emplace` in this case we get something like: `error: use of deleted function ‘Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo&&)’` which follows from the fact that...

> ...if the required location (e.g. `vec.begin()`) has been occupied by an existing element, the
> inserted element is constructed at another location at first, and then
> **move assigned** into the required location - [More here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace)

The `example_class` cannot be move assigned due to presence of `const` data members.

You still can construct elements directly in the `vec` by making sure that you not trying to construct them in place of any already existing element - by using `emplace_back().

More importantly, note that in `vec.begin()+1` you try to access beyond the currently allocated memory for the `vec` (which is empty, meaning `vec.begin() == vec.end()`). It's the same as assuming that subscripting an element after the end of a vector will add an element to it - which is wrong.